# Why is the allowNull (false) option ignored inside createTable function of sequelize

Tags: node.js, database-design, sequelize.js

I'm running [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) on node.js. For table generation there is a `queryInterface.createTable` command defined.

Why is the `allowNull: false` statement ignored when defined inside `queryInterface.createTable`? The generated column still has allowNull: true set.

Isn't the [`createTable()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-createTable) command used to create the tables after calling `sequelize.sync({force: true})`?

```
queryInterface.createTable('events', { name: { allowNull: false, type: Sequelize.STRING },...
sequelize.sync({force: true});
// > column `name` has allowNull = true

sequelize.define('events', { name: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.STRING },...
sequelize.sync({force: true});
// > column `name` has allowNull = false
```

As you can see if I define `allowNull: false` inside `sequelize.define`, the constraint is set correctly.

- "sequelize": "^5.15.0" / mysql-5.7.27-winx64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createTable()` is related to the [migration](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html) where as `sync()` sycronizes the model definitions reflecting the table schema of `define()`.

Comment: I thought `sync()` would also trigger any migration if needed - isn't it? But I don't really know when a migration is triggered.

Comment: I don't know how I can exactly put this but what `sync()` does is reflecting the changes in schema definition you made by `define()`. So it's kind of dangerous operation - you can't roll back the changes or go back and forth after some changes.

But database migration, I think you would know what it means after reading the documentation I mentioned, is more like recording every single change done to your database and tracking it like git. And `createTable()` and `queryInterface` is used for that. I believe the documentation also contains example code related to the migration.